# Microsoft Azure Cloud Shell would not work

Tags: azure-cloud-shell

I am learning about Azure now, yesterday, because I made a mess about some staff so I decide to delete all resources and start off clean. Therefore, I delete the storage account that used by azure portal shell. Now my portal shell wouldn't work.
It give me something like this:

Requesting a Cloud Shell.
PowerShell may take up to a minute.Failed to provision a Cloud Shell: {"code":"ServiceUnavailable","message":"Cloud Shell is not available at this moment, please retry later."}

Anyone has any idea on how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

If deleting your storage account you should be prompted to re-onboard into the service by creating another storage account. If you still hit this issue, try hitting the "restart" button in the iframe toolbar. If you still repeatedly hit that issue, please open a support ticket.

Details on [how storage works with Bash in Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/persisting-shell-storage) can be found here.